# Get access rules of a Sitecore role

Tags: c#, sitecore, roles

Is it possible to see a list of access rules that a particular role in Sitecore has? That is to say, is there a way to programatically take a role and view what items it has create/delete/whatever access to?

My workaround was going to be to pull a user from the group and view their access rights...but I was hoping there might be a cleaner way to pull access rights on a group itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to see a list of access rules that a particular role in Sitecore has?

[Access rights are stored in items](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-standard-template-security-section) so in order to get *all* the role access rules, you'll have to scan all the items in a database (as [Access Viewer](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/view_the_access_rights_of_a_security_account#_View_the_access) does).

For each item, you may check if there are any access permission configured for a particular *account* (user or role) and *access right*:

```
AccessRuleCollection accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
AccessRightCollection accessRights = AccessRightManager.GetAccessRights();
foreach (AccessRight accessRight in accessRights)
{
    AccessPermission accessPermission =
        accessRules.Helper.GetAccessPermission(account, accessRight, PropagationType.Entity);

    if (accessPermission != AccessPermission.NotSet)
    {
        // do smth here
    }
}
```